# How to get the width of a string within a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have some paragraphs inside a div, the paragraphs width is 100%, however I'd like to get the width only of the part filled by a string, in other words, only where there is something written.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener('click',  function()  {
      console.log(this.children[0].offsetWidth)
      console.log(this.children[1].offsetWidth)
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
}

.test > p {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.test > p:first-of-type {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
     <p>Something</p>
     <p>Any other thing</p>
</div>
```

Here I have two paragraphs, both with `width: 200px`, but the first one has the string 'something' and the second one 'any other thing', I'd like to get the width used by these strings.

Is there a way to do that?

I know I could use a div, set the background to it, put p inside it and keep `p` with only the width necessary to fit the content, what would solve my problem. But if there is a way to do what I asked, it would be my first choice.

Comment: instead of `width: 100%;` do `width: max-content;`

Comment: You could do like `<p><span id='yup'>Something</span></p>`, then `document.getElementById('yup').getBoundingClientRect().width`.

Comment: @Evik Ghazarian because I need the bg to fill 100%

Comment: Then you have to wrap it in `span` or another `div`

Comment: @StackSlave, of course, that will work. My head is so full I didn't even thought about `span`.  I can't use an `id`, but I can work around this. Thank you very much. If you want to make it an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let doc, bod, htm, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
// Tiny library for learning above - magic below
const test = S('.test');
function getSpanWidths(){
  const test_spans = Q('span', test), a = [];
  for(let q of test_spans){
    a.push(q.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }
  return a;
}
// execute before click if not dynamic
const spanWidths = getSpanWidths();
test.onclick = ()=>{
  console.clear(); console.log(spanWidths);
}
}); // end load
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
}

.test > p {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test > p:first-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <p><span>Something</span></p>
  <p><span>Any other thing</span></p>
</div>
```